# Enable jenkins services in bitbucket account

Tags: iphone, jenkins

What is the value of "END POINT URL". I am using Jenkins URL="http://localhost:8080".
Can you please explain all steps.How to we trigger Jenkins Job when we commit(PUSH) the code in repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+Service+Management).

You will find/configure **End Point** in Manage Jenkins > Configure System.

[image]

Comment: replace localhost with your system IP address.Its working fine.

Comment: For bitbucket account activate the jenkins services use this link.

for end point:-http://SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS/jenkins/job/PROJECT_NAME/build?token=TOKEN_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

it's correct change your url below

localhost replace as ip Address instead by `http://198.162.1.25`

[image]

Second image Source by:**Jesly Varghese**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a build ensure that your job can successfully checkout your project first. Then under Build Triggers check Poll SCM

In the text box, set your build trigger to fire within 3 min(or so) of the check-in. This is to reduce CPU load:

[image: trigger within 3 min]